# Facebook Wall posts - Auto reply - Python Selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, automation

I've been trying to create a Python Selenium script to reply to facebook wall posts.

I'll be naive in describing the problem since I'm learning both python, selenium and HTML as a beginner.

I'm not able to find a clickable element in my wall and click on the element. When I do manually click, there is a JS element which seems to create an editable element where I can write my comment as reply.

But finding the element to click is really tricky. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code snippet I've used.

```
mydriver.get(baseurl)
mydriver.maximize_window()

mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).clear()
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).send_keys(username)
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).clear()
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).send_keys(password)
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()

post_box = mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector(".UFIAddCommentInput")
ActionChains(mydriver).move_to_element(post_box).click().perform()
print("InputContainer Selected")
post_box=mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_1mf _1mj']")
post_box.send_keys("Testing using Name not ID. Selenium is easy.")
post_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
print ("Posted...")
```

Here is where I'm trying to register the comment.
http://prntscr.com/bsxmsm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that´s surely not allowed, you should read the platform policy...